# Android MapView Marker Text title not shown

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on Google Map I am facing an issue, I am trying to show title on marker but its not shown.

My Code

```
    private void updateMarkerWithCircle(LatLng position, double radius,
        float zoomLevel) {
    mMap.clear();
    // double radiusInMeters = radius * 100.0;
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(position)
            .radius(radius).fillColor(CIRCLE_shadeColor)
            .strokeColor(CIRCLE_strokeColor).strokeWidth(5);
    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position);
    markerOptions.draggable(true);
    markerOptions.title("Example");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
            CIRCLE_LATITUDE, CIRCLE_LONGITUDE), zoomLevel));
}
```

How can I show it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void updateMarkerWithCircle(LatLng position, double radius,
    float zoomLevel) {
    mMap.clear();
    // double radiusInMeters = radius * 100.0;
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(position)
            .radius(radius).fillColor(CIRCLE_shadeColor)
            .strokeColor(CIRCLE_strokeColor).strokeWidth(5);
    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    mMap.addMarker(newMarkerOptions().position(position).title("Example").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).draggable(true));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
        CIRCLE_LATITUDE, CIRCLE_LONGITUDE), zoomLevel));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I would recommend you to use the html tag in title. 

function setMarker(p) {

    var title = '<div><img src="icon_header_i_focus.png" onClick = "getDetails('
            + n
            + ')" /><div id ="place" style = "height:100%;width:100%" onClick = "getDetails('

            + ')"><label for="Name">'
            + PlaceName
            + '</label><br><label for="Address">'
            + PlaceAddress
            + '</label> </div><div id= "direction" ><a  href="javascript:getDirections('

            + ')">directions</a>'
            + '</div></div>';


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon : markerImage,
        map : map,
        position : pos,
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        if (infowindow) {
            infowindow.close();
        }
        ;
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : title,
            maxWidth : 300
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```